# Django class based views get post data and send response

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Working on an Api I wanted to give class based views in Django a go.

This is what I got so far:

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .api import Api

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', Api.as_view())
]
```

#### api.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.views.generic import View    

class Api(View):    
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Api, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("result")

    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("result")
```

When calling this code from Postman I keep getting 2 issues:

#### Post data

In postman I have set a value in the Post headers but when I use the debugger to check the POST data it just isn't there.

#### Return HttpResponse

I keep getting the error `The view api.api.Api didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

When I change the post method to a get method and send a get request with Postman I get the same result.

Comment: Please show your actual code; the snippet above has a typo which means it could never run.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have copy pasted the actual code.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do:

```
return super(Api, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You're not returning anything, and a function returns `None` by default.

Also, you probably want your url as `r'^$'`

Comment: This fixed the issue with the return value. But I still do not receive any post data. Could you help me out on that too?

Comment: This fixed it for me. In the constructor you want to return something i.e
`return super(Api, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)`